# Zip content of folder Java

Tags: java, zip, unzip

I am trying to zip the content of the folder. Meaning when I unzip the zip I don't want to get the folder but the content of the folder. Content is various files and subfolder

Problem: However when I do this, the zip that gets created does not show my files it only shows the folders. When I use different unzip utilities I can see that the files are there. It feels like some kind of security setting was applied or maybe they are made hidden. I need to be able to see the files as it is causing problems with my other programs.

The structure should look like this

- zip

  - my.html
  - my.css
  - otherfolder

NOT LIKE THIS

- zip

  - MyFolder

    - my.html
    - my.css
    - otherfolder

Here is the code I am using

```
//create flat zip
  FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(myfolder +".zip");
  ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);
  File folder = new File(myfolder);
   for (String fileName: folder.list()) {
        FileUtil.addFileToZip("", myfolder + "/" + fileName, zip);
    }
   zip.flush();
   zip.close();
 //end create zip
```

Here is the code in my FileUtil

```
  public static void addFileToZip(String path, String srcFile,ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File(srcFile);
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
          addFolderToZip(path, srcFile, zip);
        }
        else {
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
          zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            zip.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          zip.closeEntry();
          zip.flush();
          in.close();
          //zip.close(); 
        }
   }

  public static void addFolderToZip(String path, String srcFolder, ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File(srcFolder);
        //System.out.println("Source folder is "+srcFolder+" into file "+folder);
        for (String fileName: folder.list()) {
          if (path.equals("")) {
            addFileToZip(folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName, zip);
          }
          else {
          //System.out.println("zipping "+path + "/" + folder.getName()+" and file "+srcFolder + "/" + fileName);
            addFileToZip(path + "/" + folder.getName(), srcFolder + "/" + fileName,  zip);
          }
        }
      }
```

Thank you for any help in advance, I feel like it is just a minor thing that I might be missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `addFileToZip` method, you have

```
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
```

You will get a `"/"` appended with `folder.getName()` when the `path` is blank. This could be your problem?

Try

```
if (path.equals("")) {
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder.getName()));
}
else {
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + "/" + folder.getName()));
}
```